# Any way to count a total number of buttons in a cucumber test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

So I've got some cucumber tests, and at one point there's a line that says "Then there should be button 1". But this can be seen multiple times with the number changing to how many buttons there are.

I was wondering if there was any way for me to keep track during the cucumber test and not finding the same button as before.

Or would I have to just write, "Then there should be a button with (.?)" do |text| to make it easier?

Comment: you may check http://www.tamingthemindmonkey.com/2012/02/16/capybara-have-selector-and-count-error-messages, have_selector seems to supports count and so does have_css

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question I would suggest using a table.

Example:

In feature

```
Then I should see the following buttons:
   |Name              |
   |Button 1          |
   |Some other button |
   |Another button    |
```

In steps

```
/^I should see the following buttons:$/ do |table|
    table.hashes.each do |row|
       page.should have_button(row[:Name])
    end           
end
```